# Where can I find login/password information for connecting to local openSSH server started in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-7, putty

I opened passwd file in etc directory but didn't find something useful. While installing openSSH I set password but for all usernames I input this pass I got "access denied". As SSH client I'm using PuttY.Where can I find right log/pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Putty cyrillic encode. Login/password for SSH are same with existing Windows 7 login/passwords. Using console SSH instead of PuttY solved the problem.